# JSTL aparece en HTML

Tags: java, jsp

Que tal! Me encuentro haciendo una pequeña aplicación de Spring (estoy aprendiendo) y me he topado con que, al pasar como parámetro un objeto List a la vista (JSP), el ciclo `forEach` no funciona como debe. En realidad sí uno busca en el HTML aparecen los objetos, pero no se si estoy accediendo bien a sus atributos del objeto, aunque me consta que sí estan bien definidos, este es mi código:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project Name</th><th>Sponsor Name</th><th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${projects}" var="project"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>${project.name}</td><td>${project.sponsor}</td><td>${project.description}</td> 
                    </tr> 
                </c:forEach> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Esta es la salida en el HTML:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project Name</th><th>Sponsor Name</th><th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="[com.pyxis.mvc.data.entities.Project@327b6991, com.pyxis.mvc.data.entities.Project@60e256f9, com.pyxis.mvc.data.entities.Project@6412e13d]" var="project"> 
                    <tr>
                        <td></td><td></td><td></td> 
                    </tr> 
                </c:forEach> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

He agregado el taglib `<c:>` directamente al JSP pero me da un error de compilación, cuando lo quito compila sin problemas. Estoy usando NetBeans y pues no se me ocurre nada, espero puedan ayudarme, saludos!

Así agrego mi objeto a la vista:

```
@Autowired
private ProjectService projectService;

@RequestMapping(value = "project/find", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String find(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("projects", this.projectService.findAll());
    return "ProjectFindView";
}
```

Comment: También me asegure que las dependencias de Maven fueran las correctas

Comment: el `forEach` es correcto, ademas se ve que tienes 3 objetos dentro de la lista.... puedes mostrar el codigo java de como declaras y le pasas la lista `projects` a la vista?

Comment: Listo, he agregadro el código! :)

Comment: Este es mi código http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8743/org-springframework-beans-factory-beancreationexception-error-creating-bean-wit

Answer (score 3):

He logrado hacer funcionar mi código, si les pasa sólo fijense en [esta tablita](http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/04/24/how-to-reference-and-use-jstl-in-your-web-application/) y agreguen su dependencia al pom.xml y a su archivo jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```